# Google map doesn't appear in my android application

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

the map doesn't appear in my app and  I can't figure out what's the problem at my code I've tried my best to resolve this problem, hope u could help me to resolve this ,here's the main layout :

```
     <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#fffffbec"
    android:id="@+id/heady">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="127dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="0.86"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/bodylay"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/acquiring_signal_layout"
            android:background="#fff8edff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01"
                style="@color/green"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/acquiring_signal_label"
                android:layout_width="275dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/acquiring_signal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ff12bec1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/MapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="274dp"
            android:apiKey="0oR0G95fEqsQy8FGrgFXeZ4U3NnHNmRZUbPh_8A"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.81" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SendButton"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/send_button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ff12bec1"
        android:layout_weight="0.11"
        android:textColor="#fffefff3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the mainfest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto"
    package="com.mylocation.hanan.mylocation" >
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="13" android:minSdkVersion="9"></uses-sdk>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" >
        <!--@style/AppTheme-->
     <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>

        <activity
            android:name="com.mylocation.hanan.mylocation.Sharelocation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mylocation.hanan.mylocation.Preferences"
            android:label="@string/preferences_activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mylocation.hanan.mylocation.action.Preferences" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: add api key to your manifest file - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup

Comment: You are using v1, should update to v2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points to be noted:

**1.** You are using an older version of Google Map which is no longer supported.

**2.** You might be using the wrong API keys.

**3.** You haven't added the proper permissions on the manifest file.

**4.** Make sure you have included the Google Play Services library to your project.

Possible solutions,

**A.** Add a support map fragment in your xml,

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**B.** Use the support map fragment in your activity and implement onMapReadyCallback

```
public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));
    }
}
```

Source:

[Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

**C.** Add proper permissions on the manifest file,

```
    <!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="YOUR_GOOGLE_MAP_APIKEY" />
```

**D.** To get a Google Maps API key follow the instructions here,

[Get a Google Maps API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get-key)